# Magento Page Builder default styling

Tags: magento2, page-builder, default-values

Page builder has defaults for most element styles e.g. like this:

[image: margin and padding]

Out of the box it appears in this case the defaults are an unexpected 0 which means no default margins between columns - all are bunched up together. Seems wrong that customers have to individually style all columns instead of there being appropriate defaults.

Anyone know where these defaults are set?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't see it, It's going to use the default value of element, in case of setting value of zero, It might related to issue of Page Builder did not either not showing the value in Backend or Frontend got issue,

I faced this issue before and get rid of it using the another module like this one https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder/

Hope this can help